# Function Continuity on an Interval.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I must show that $f(x)=p{\sqrt{x}}$ , $p>0$ is continuous on the interval [0,1).

I'm not sure how I show that a function is continuous on an interval, as opposed to at a particular point.

Comment: What you wrote is a *constant* function, continuous everywhere. Did you mean $\,p\sqrt x\,$?

Comment: Assume $x_0\in[0,1)$ and show that $f$ is continuous at the particular point $x_0$. (Note that the case $x_0=0$ may deserve special treatment)

Comment: Yes, DonAntonio. Sorry!

Comment: Do you mean to take the $p$th root?

Comment: No - p is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly consider the case where $x_0 \in (0,1)$ then:  $$ |f(x)-f(x_0)| =|p{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0})}|= |p|\lvert{x-x_0 \over \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{x_0}}\rvert = |p|{|x-x_0| \over \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{x_0}} \tag{1}$$

We want to show that this gets small as we move toward $x_0$. Take the distance of $x$ from $x_0$ to be less than $\epsilon_0$. and we have:

$$|x-x_0|< \epsilon_0$$
$$x_0-\epsilon_0 < x < \epsilon_0 + x_0$$
$$\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} < \sqrt{x} \tag{*}$$
$$\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0} < \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{x_0}$$
$${1 \over \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{x_0}}<{1 \over\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0} }$$
$${|p||x-x_0| \over \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{x_0}}<{|p||x-x_0| \over\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0} }$$

And so we have bounded $(1)$. Also note that the step in $(*)$ is justified as $x_0$ is inside an $\textit{open}$ interval and so an $\epsilon_0$ exist so that the qauntity $x_0-\epsilon_0>0$.

Then we want ${|p||x-x_0| \over\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0} }<\epsilon$ so we start in reverse assuming what we want and then work back up the chain of reasoning to show it is true.

$${|p||x-x_0| \over\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0} }<\epsilon \quad \Leftrightarrow$$
$$|p||x-x_0|<\epsilon (\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0} ) \quad \Leftrightarrow$$
$$|x-x_0| < {\epsilon(\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0})\over |p|} $$

So by taking $|x-x_0|< \min({\epsilon(\sqrt{x_0-\epsilon_0} +\sqrt{x_0})\over |p|} , \epsilon_0)$ we have that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ and it is continuous for all $x_0 \in (0,1)$

Now for the case of continuity at $0$ clearly this can only be continuous from the right as $f$ is not defined for negative values. So we wish to show that $|p \sqrt{x} - 0|=|p\sqrt{x}|  = |p|\sqrt{x}< \epsilon$ for $x $ such that $0<x<\delta$. Again assume what you want and we can work backwards.

$$|p|\sqrt{x}<\epsilon$$
$$\sqrt{x}<{\epsilon \over |p|}$$
$$x<({\epsilon \over |p|})^2$$

So take $\delta = ({\epsilon \over |p|})^2$ and your done :-).

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

Choose $c\in[0,1);$

- $c>0:|x-c|<\delta\implies|\sqrt  x-\sqrt  c||\sqrt  x +\sqrt  c|<\delta\implies|\sqrt x-\sqrt  c|<\dfrac{\delta}{\sqrt x+\sqrt c}\le\dfrac{\delta}{\sqrt c};$
- $c=0:0\le x<\epsilon^2\implies0\le\sqrt x<\epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

An important theorem here :

> If $f'$ is continuous and defined on an interval I, then $f$ is also defined and continuous on I.

Using this theorem, we get $f'(x)\frac{p}{2\sqrt{x}}$. $f'$ is not defined only for $x\in\Bbb R_-$. So $f$ is continuous for $x>0$, therefore on $]0,1]$.